# How to adjust prices depending on quantity and attributes using Drupal Commerce?

Tags: 7, commerce

I am using [Drupal Commerce](https://www.drupal.org/project/commerce), and have a question about some of the available price/quantity modules. As an example, if people want to buy 1-5 pictures, the price is $49/each, if 6-10, than it is going to be $39 per each.

I found *[Commerce Price Table](https://www.drupal.org/project/commerce_price_table)* (1st) and *[Commerce Pricelist](https://www.drupal.org/project/commerce_pricelist)* (2nd) modules for that. Looks like 2nd is more functional, but it is very "new" ... Not sure which one I should go for.

Or should I consider some other module(s) that are also popular for that? Or can I do it right from [Drupal Commerce](https://www.drupal.org/project/commerce)?

What I am actually looking for: a way which can adjust the price depending on **quantity** and **attributes**.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Module comparison

I'm not familiar with any other such pricing related modules. It seems to me that you will have to decide between these options:

- A stable module (aka the price "table" module).
- A module that's on the horizon (aka the price "list" module).

Whenever I have to decide between multiple modules, I often use the (23) criteria that I ever documented in "[maintenance scorecards](https://www.drupal.org/node/2363985#scorecards)" (within the Community documentation). Those scorecards are actually "applied" to charting modules, but the same criteria can be used, I think, to mostly any type of module comparisons.

I'd be happy to provide some more details (via a next iteration of my answer), but if I was to decide I would definitely go for the stable, commonly used price "table" module. The major "red flag" (= no go) for the newer "list" module is criterium nr 26 (downloads vs reported installs ratio). Correct me if I'm wrong, but only like 10 % of downloads seem to have resulted in sites that continue using it.

## Rules is your friend

I would definitely also consider the [Rules](https://www.drupal.org/project/rules) module, using some custom Rules, something like so:

- Events = Calculate Sell Price of Product.
- Actions = calculate the price, and set the price to the calculated value.

Not sure (yet) if you'd need some extra 'Conditions' added to this.

Refer to [Drupal commerce and rules: changing the product price dynamically](http://www.drupalwoo.com/content/blog/drupal-commerce-and-rules-changing-product-price-dynamically) for an example of dynamically changing product prices.

## Create your own custom Rule

If for some reason you can't get it to work with the [Rules](https://www.drupal.org/project/rules) module, then I'd consider writing my own custom Rule(s), similar to what is described in [Drupal custom Rules how to write your own events conditions, actions and custom object](http://dominiquedecooman.com/blog/drupal-custom-rules-how-write-your-own-events-conditions-actions-and-custom-object-custom-token).

The main steps that are detailed in this tutorial are further described below (with the code included below quoted from that link).

### Part 1: Defining the Event, Condition and Action

#### Define the Rules Event

```
/**
* Implementation of hook_rules_event_info().
* @ingroup rules
*/
function your_module_rules_event_info() {
  return array(
    'your_module_package_bought' => array(
      'label' => t('A package was bought'),
      'module' => 'your_module',
      'arguments' => array(
        'acting_user' => array('type' => 'user', 'label' => t('The user who bought the package.')),
        'package' => array('type' => 'package', 'label' => t('The purchased package.')),
      ),
    ),
  );
}
```

#### Define the Rules Condition

```
/**
 * implementation of hook_rules_condition_info()
 */
function your_module_rules_condition_info() {
  return array(
    'your_module_condition_package_type' => array(
      'label' => t('Type of the package'),
      'arguments' => array(
        'package_id' => array('type' => 'value', 'label' => t('The type of the purchased package.')),
        'package_type' => array('type' => 'string', 'label' => t('The type of the purchased package is')),
      ),
      'module' => 'your_module',
    ),
  );
}
```

#### Define the Rules Action

```
/**
 * Implementation of hook_rules_action_info().
 */
function packages_rules_action_info() {
  return array(
    'your_module_action_change_order_status' => array(
      'label' => t('Change the order status'),
      'arguments' => array(
        'order' => array('type' => 'value', 'label' => t('The order object.')),
      ),
      'module' => 'your_module',
    ),
  );
}
```

### Part 2: Coding the custom Event, Condition and Action

#### Event:

Somewhere in your custom module, you need to include logic to trigger the event, with something similar to this example (note the `your_module_package_bought` in it):

```
  //here the code for buying a package will be located
  //when that code returns that a package was bought trigger the rule
  $order = order_load($oid);//$oid will be the id of the order made
  $package = package_load($pid);//pid will be the id of the bought package
  global $user;
  rules_invoke_event('your_module_package_bought', $user, $package, $order);
```

#### Condition:

To evaluate the Rules condition (to check if it is TRUE or FALSE), the function `your_module_condition_package_type` is executed using the arguments provided. Here is an example of how such function could look like:

```
function your_module_condition_package_type($pid, $type) {
  $package = package_load($pid);
  return ($package->type == $type) ? true : false;
}
```

#### Action:

Somewhere in your custom module, you need to include logic to perform the actual action, in this example it should be done within the function named `your_module_action_change_order_status`.

Comment: Tried these two modules. 2nd is a little unstable. 1st works fine, BUT. If I need different prices for attributes, than I also have to fill price/ quantity for this attributes as well. Looks like that is a lot of work. In my case it is not too my, but I think there is rational way. I thought it works like: calculate total price for product depend on quantity and THAN add attribute price and multiple on this amount of items. I think I have to try Rules now...

Comment: I can imagine that it might be a lot of work if you have many attributes. But I believe it is "a" way to gt it to work. Otherwise you have to consider some type of custom module with some custom Rule (which may be "a lot of work" too, first to write such module, later on to maintain it. Because keep in mind that those prices may need to be changed some day also ... (that's why I'd hesitate to write a custom module for it).

Comment: quick question. Are you a programmer? What if we would ask you to write a module like that, how much can it cost?

Comment: i sent you message on drupal.org, but not sure if you did it right :) can you please email me? ildarn@gmail.com