# How to force a cron run after a Rules component is scheduled?

Tags: 7, rules, cron

This question is a sequel on [Why is the database not updated before a next Rule is launched?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/173939/why-is-the-database-not-updated-before-a-next-rule-is-launched). I have a Rule that schedules a Rules component 5 seconds after the current time (this number is arbitrarily chosen). Since this component uses information from a frequently changing View, it should be executed as soon as possible. However, in my current configuration, that only happens when cron is run; which takes place once in an hour.

Can I somehow force a cron run (eventually with Rules) when the Rules component is scheduled?

Comment: The best I can think of for implementing a Rules Action to for cron to run, is to create your own custom Rules Action, in which you invoke [drupal_cron_run](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!common.inc/function/drupal_cron_run/7.x)

Comment: @Pierre.Vriens: That sounds like a great idea to me if that is easier/better for performance than using another module like Elysia Cron or Ultimate Cron.

Comment: Now you make me doubt if I should write that down as an actual answer ...

Comment: @Pierre.Vriens: Haha, you are the expert here, so the decision is yours. I am new to cron and stuff, so I don't really know what the best practices are or what the drawbacks of a frequently running cron are.

Comment: I'd be interested in an answer that doesn't involve a custom Rules Action, I can't imagine nobody ever had a similar requirement. Maybe somebody like @NiallMurphy might come up with an interesting solution ...

Comment: Or otherwise @rooby ??? PS: If you're in a hurry and want to give such custom Rules Action a try, you may want to look at [this answer](http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/166023/how-to-adjust-prices-depending-on-quantity-and-attributes-using-drupal-commerce/166026#166026) for a basic getting started with custom Rules Events / Conditions / Actions ...

Answer (score 0):

you can give this module a try , it makes it possible to run cron via configurable rules 
[Ultimate cron](https://www.drupal.org/project/ultimate_cron)

Comment: I'd be interested how to "configure" those "rules", using this module, so that cron is triggered "when the Rules component is scheduled" (as in the question.